# 24VDC PLC with 12VDC inputs

Tags: plc

I have a 24 VDC PLC. It is powered by a power supply that takes in 12 V and turns it into 24 V. This 12 V is coming from a car battery. The inputs for this PLC is 12 V.

Here is the smart relay:
It is a phoenix Contact PLC model PLC-V8C/PT-24DC/SAM.
[image: PLC Tech Data]

Here is the power supply: MINI-PS-12-24DC/24DC/1 also from Phoenix Contact
[image]

I have a separate 12 V system (which is also run by the same 12 V car battery) which has a switch in it. The positive side of this switch I have going to an input on the PLC. This does not produce 12 V on the PLC input. The only reason I know of is that the grounds are not connected.

I have tried connecting both grounds, one from the 12 V side and then the one coming out of the 24 V power supply. This is pulling my 12 V input down to 1.75 V for some reason.

How should this be wired to the PLC can read the 12 V input?

[image]

Comment: More information about the 12V/24V boost-converter (make, model, datasheet)? How much current can the "12V board" source?

Comment: Can you specify the PLC you are using?

Comment: @RonBeyer I added links to what I am using.

Comment: The smart relay link is broken. Link to the datasheet, not the overview page or, even better, put enough info into your question so that we don't have to follow a link.

Comment: I added more information

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpgc5S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay isolation between two systems.*

You have been vague about the type if inputs on your PLC - current sourcing or sinking - so you may have a little work to do adapting this solution.